# How to add items in the DDL after data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my site when the user logs in he will be having option like Editmyaccount where he can edit the details.Here i am displaying the values entered by him in the registration page from DB and i am having two DDL's there i am displying appropriate country and state selected by user but i want to show some other countries and states along with it how can i do this?

```
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ProfileMasterDAL.bind();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select country--");
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Actually i am getting DDL from other page using session

```
  DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["country"].ToString()));
           DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["state"].ToString()));
```

Comment: Have you pre-populated the DropDownList before you bound it, with say the values from your Cities table?

Comment: No i dont have any country and state table in the DB,i am having the values in a XML.

Comment: That could work too, populate the DDL Items collection before you bind the DDL to the saved user data.

Comment: yeah will do it,but i want to display like whatever country value comes from the DB i want to show the states corresponding to it is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, if you have alink set up between counties and states.

Comment: When i pre-populate the country DDL i am getting the countries but the country from the DB is not getting highlighted.

Comment: Is that country part of the pre-populated list? What are the Items you are populating into the list? Are you using SelectedValue or SelectedText? When Adding the Item, are you using a code and name combo, or purely a name? Are the Cases the same?

Comment: Yes the country is there in pre-populated list,i am populating list of countries from the XML.I have updated the question check once.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding a list of countries/states to the DropDownList already, you can then bind the selected value of both lists to the value(s) stored in session. For example, if you country DropDownList looked like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Please Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Australia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>United Kingdom</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Spain</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You could select the appropriate country specified in the session using this code:

```
 DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session["country"].ToString()
```

That way, you don't need to add in extra items programatically.

Comment: But i want to show like if the country is USA show the related states in the states DDL not all the states?How can i do this?

Comment: You could use the country session as a parameter when retrieving the data to populate the second datalist. Then you would just do the same as above and use the session to set the `SelectedValue`.

Comment: I am doing like this when the DDL selected values is == to session value i am populating states DDL with appropriate states from XML but  i am getting duplicate value as one i am getting from session and another is from XMl how can i avoid this?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't need these two lines of code:

DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["country"].ToString()));
DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(Session["state"].ToString()));

If you are binding the dropdowns and then setting the SelectedValue from the session.

Comment: Can i get the state values using the session value of the country??

Comment: You can, you'd just have to use it as a parameter in whatever database query you are using. You'd only return the states where the country = the country in session.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion why can't you retrieve everything using a generic class
and then add the values from session before binding it to the drop down list then you can 
do something like

```
var distinctStatelist
    = list.GroupBy(
        i => i.state,
        (key, group) => group.First()
    ).ToList();
```

which will get you the distinct  state list and then you can be sure that you don't have duplicates and bind this to your dropdownlist.

**OR**

If you already have the item in the drop down list then you can do this

```
DropDownList i = default(DropDownList);
ListItem li = i.Items.FindByText("");
i.Items.Remove(li);
li.Selected = true;
i.Items.Add(li);
```

Comment: The problem after displaying the country and state of the user in DDL is i want to give an option to update the details so i want to add countries and states in the DDL's.